# How to filter specific files on a list in folder comparison in BeyondCompare?

Tags: filter, directory, compare, bc, beyondcompare

I have a lot of files and subfolders in two similar folders called "C:\AAA\BBB\P" and "C:\AAA\CCC\P".
I want to compare only specific files from a fullpath list and ignore the other files using Beyond compare.

e.g. Here the list of files i want to compare:

```
C:\AAA\BBB\P\Ade.AutomationShell.UIImpl\Cockpit\Presenter\LedPresenter.cs
C:\AAA\BBB\P\Ade.Compare.Network\Trees\NetworkNodeTreeFactory.cs
C:\AAA\BBB\P\Ade.Compiler.PlcNextImpl\Tasks\GenerateConfigurationFolder.cs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare specific files using filters in BeyondCompare.

Include the filter of files as shown in the next picture.
[image: Add Filters from the provided list]

It is important to notice that you cannot include the full path. You have to include **an astherisk** for the file list path after "C:\AAA\BBB\P".

[image: Result of comparison after applying the filter]